# Is there any method in Rails that creates basic structure for migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

For example I have the following code:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string  "name"
end
```

Instead of appending strings myself, I'd like to call some method that would build basic migration skeleton for it like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string  "name"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails you can use the available generators to define a large amount of boilerplate code, including migrations.

To create (most of) your example, you could use this command:

```
bin/rails generate migration CreateUsers name:string
```

This will generate the following migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table "users" do |t|
      t.string  "name"
    end
  end
end
```

The [Rails guide on Active Record migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration) describes this in more detail. Please read this and some of the other guides for basic usage of the rails environment.